# How to send data (2 strings) from a next.js server to a node.js server and then update values on the node.js server with the new data

Tags: node.js, api, server, next.js

Apologies if I sound uneducated on the matter, I have never used JS until a few days ago and don't have much server/API experience.

Essentially I am using nextauth.js to authenticate a users twitter account and allow them to sign into an app. Next.js is providing them with a sign in option and once they sign in and authorize the app I now have access to their api key/ secret.

I also created an app in node.js that will allow me to change their twitter header for them. This runs on a separate port. I need to be able to send the key/secret I get from the next.js app to the node server so that I can use these keys to make the changes to their account. I am unsure of how to do this and what type of requests are required.

Ive spend a good amount of time looking into online resources but I haven't been able to conceptualize it fully. Any help/resources/explanations would be very appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

if you have access to secret key you wanna send on the client-side you can simply use fetch

```
const response = await fetch('https://yourbackend.url/here', {
  method: 'POST', // make sure the method is set to POST
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({secretKey: "yourseceretkeyhereaslkdaasldkaslkdjlask"}) // send the secret as payload in the body
}).then(res => res.json())
  .catch(console.log);
```

catching the payload on your server will totally depend on what kind of server you have setup.